# how to eliminate outlier in spotfire box plots

Tags: max, min, box, spotfire, outliers

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: in the chart or table underneath the chart?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the values to `MAX()` values would skew the data even if it were possible. There are two hacks to do this though.

1. Right Click > Properties > Y-Axis > set the `MIN` range value and `MAX` range values to something that would eliminate all outliers. This is really only suitable for box plots that are close in all values to each other (all percentiles)
2. On your toolbar click Insert > Calculated Column > choose the correct data table and paste in the expression below. You will need to replace the [x-axisColumn] and the [y-axisColumn] with what ever is on the X and Y axis of your box plot. To find out what this is, right click on your box plot > properties > X-Axis and there it will tell you what your X-Axis column is. Do this for the Y-Axis as well.  This will create a column called "Outlier" in your data table with three options: NotOutlier, UpperOutlier, LowerOutlier. You just need to uncheck "UpperOutlier" and "LowerOutlier" to remove your outliers.

`

```
case
when [y-axisColumn]<(Q1([y-axisColumn]) - (1.5 * IQR([y-axisColumn]) OVER ([x-axisColumn]))) then "LowerOutlier"
when [y-axisColumn]>(Q3([y-axisColumn]) + (1.5 * IQR([y-axisColumn]) OVER ([x-axisColumn]))) then "UpperOutlier"
else "NotOutlier"
end as [Outlier]
```

`

Comment: i added the dynamic solution for you. Just change the x and y axis column names to what ever columns you have in your box plot.

Comment: You will click insert on the toolbar and click calculated column. This is where you will add this new column @Raj. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @raj can you attach a screen shot of your chart

Comment: Sure in 15 minutes I'll create a room

Comment: @raj i am chatting you now in that link

Comment: That's unfortunate. I will updated my answer to be super complete.

Comment: @raj the answer has been updated. This should completely resolve your solution so consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: You will need to use Intersect(). I can not help further without access to your data. Good luck.

Comment: You'll have to figure it out @Raj i have helped a lot on your question and it hasn't even been upvoted as helpful. Providing a formula which you won't understand will only lead to further questions. We all enjoy helping but have jobs that we get paid for ourselves. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Raj was this helpful

Comment: @Raj that should be asked in a new question to gain more attention. You should also accept and up its answers which were helpful and / or correct.