# How to get numbers from string in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

How to extract numbers from string in spotfire ...

Example:

Input column: ACD:1234F

Output column: 1234

Help is really aprreciated

Comment: Hey Raj. Will this always be the format? 3 letters, colon, 4 numbers then a letter?

Comment: Will the numbers always be together or could it be AB12CD34ED

Comment: This is doable but I noticed you haven't accepted any answers on your previous questions nor have you invited them. Why is that?

Comment: Upvoted not invited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at these questions you posted and accept the answers if you feel they are correct. I know for certain they are correct.

[Spotfire IF Statement in Custom Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589178/spotfire-if-statement-in-custom-expression)

[how to eliminate outlier in spotfire box plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397514/how-to-eliminate-outlier-in-spotfire-box-plots)

For this case, this will extract numbers. Just replace [Column1] with what ever your column is.

```
RXReplace([Column1],"(?!\\d).","","gis")



Column1     NumberExtract
1a2b3c4d    1234
123abc345   123345
abc123def   123
```

Comment: Very brilliant. Could you explain what exactly is this? It's a regular expression. Could you share some resources where to study these?

Answer (score 4):

the following expression uses Regular Expressions to strip all non-numeric characters from a string:

```
RXReplace([col], "[^0-9]", "", "g")
```

some samples:

```
INPUT               OUTPUT
abc123              123
123abc123           123123
oi3eliu2h4rli24j    3242
```

as you notice this will simply strip the non-numerics and combine all digits into one string. it does not account for the first or second instance of a number. if you have edge cases, you'll need to share some more data for us to help.

**if this solves your issue, please don't forget to accept the answer.**

Comment: thanks @scsimon! haha nice timing on both our answers I see xD

Comment: For sure @niko. I need to upgrade to 7.x but have been procrastinating due to resources. Any advice on skipping 7.0 and going from 6.5 to 7.5?

Comment: I created a spotfire chatroom; let's take this off the comments :) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43977/spotfire

Comment: Quick help needed: Left([Week],4) is not working? Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: @raj post another question with this and some sample data. I'm sure it's an easy quick fix.