# LEFT function usage in spotfire

Tags: left-join, spotfire

Below formula is not working. Does anyone know the reason.

```
Left([Week],4)
```

is not working?

Week is column name

Comment: Raj what's in the column [Week] and what do you want out of the column? I assume the left 4 characters?

Comment: What is it returning when you use the formula?

Comment: Showing error .. not accepting the formula

Comment: please post an image of the error in your post.

Comment: Error message: Invalid type for function called left

Comment: The below will work for you. Also, again, please visit your previous posts and accept answers if they are correct....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589178/spotfire-if-statement-in-custom-expression
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397514/how-to-eliminate-outlier-in-spotfire-box-plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the LEFT most 4 characters use `LEFT()`. If you want the **RIGHT**, aka **LAST** 4 characters use `RIGHT()`

```
RIGHT('201234',4) will return 1234
LEFT('201234',4) will return 2012
```

**This can be used in a calculated column or anywhere else on a `STRING`. If your column is an `Integer` or `Decimal` or anything else you need to cast it.**

```
RIGHT(String([Week]),4) will return 1234 when the value is 201234 
LEFT(String([Week]),4) will return 2012 when the value is 201234
```